# Get mysql records based upon checkbox (selected/unselected) and export to ms excel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a html form with php, on that page
[image]

I want to get records from mysql based upon the selected checkboxes , so if a checkbox is checked it should only export the CustomerID with whom the value of the checkbox(es) have.
If not checked or filled those customer shouldn't be displayed in the excel file.

On the form I also have a button (export button), this is to be clicked after selecting the checkboxes , and export it to excel.

Here are the form with the checkboxes and the code for the export .
but when i click on (Export) buton , nothing happened , i read my code a lot of times but i didn't find where i failed

My code so far below.

**index.php**

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "123456", "test7");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_customer";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
?>
<html>  

 <head>  
  <title>Export MySQL data to Excel in PHP</title>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
 </head>  

 <body>  
  <div class="container">  
   <br />  
   <br />  
   <br />  
    <div class="table-responsive">  
        <h2 align="center">Export MySQL data to Excel in PHP</h2><br /> 
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>  
                         <th>CustomerID</th>  
                         <th>Name</th>  
                         <th>Address</th>  
                         <th>City</th>  
                         <th>Postal Code</th>
                         <th>Country</th>
                         <th>select</th>
                </tr>

  <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
   ?>
     <tr id="<?php echo $row["CustomerID"]; ?>" >
      <td><?php echo $row["CustomerID"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["CustomerName"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["Address"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["City"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["PostalCode"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["Country"]; ?></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="customer_id[]" class="export_customer" value="<?php echo $row["CustomerID"]; ?>" /></td>
     </tr>
   <?php
    }
   ?>

    </table>
    <br />
            <div align="center">
                <button type="button" name="export" id="export" class="btn btn-success">Export</button>
            </div>

   </div>  
  </div>  

 </body>  

</html>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#export').click(function(){

  if(confirm("Are you sure you want to export this?"))
  {
    var id = [];

        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
            id[i] = $(this).val();
        });

    if(id.length === 0) //tell you if the array is empty
        {
            alert("Please Select atleast one checkbox");
        }
    else
        {
            $.ajax({
            url:'export.php',
            method:'POST',
            data:{id:id},
            success:function()
        {
    for(var i=0; i<id.length; i++)
        {
            $('tr#'+id[i]+'').css('background-color', '#ccc');
            $('tr#'+id[i]+'').fadeOut('slow');
        }
        }

    });
   }

  }
  else
  {
   return false;
  }
 });

});
</script>
```

**export.php**

```
<?php  
//export.php  
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "123456", "test7");
$output = '';
if(isset($_POST["id"]))
{
 foreach($_POST["id"] as $id)
 {
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_customer WHERE CustomerID = '".$id."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
 {
  $output .= '
   <table class="table" bordered="1">  
                    <tr>  
                         <th>Name</th>  
                         <th>Address</th>  
                         <th>City</th>  
       <th>Postal Code</th>
       <th>Country</th>
                    </tr>
  ';
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
   $output .= '
    <tr>  
                         <td>'.$row["CustomerName"].'</td>  
                         <td>'.$row["Address"].'</td>  
                         <td>'.$row["City"].'</td>  
                         <td>'.$row["PostalCode"].'</td>  
                         <td>'.$row["Country"].'</td>
    </tr>
   ';
  }
  $output .= '</table>';
  header('Content-Type: application/xls');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.xls');
  echo $output;
 }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Please check you are getting array of all checked row customer ids by alert

Comment: please sir  @Mahantesh , explain more i dont understand u

Comment: You have written .each() function to get all checked customer ids. So check that you are getting all Ids in the jquery id array variable. Or else use map function

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting customer ids in the jquery 'id' variable then use this code.

Replace

```
  var id = []; $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){ id[i] = $(this).val(); });
```

By this

```
 var ids = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function(){ 
                            return $(this).val();
                       }).get();
```

Comment: unfortunately even i changed the code , when i click on the Export button i can't export the excel file

Comment: Is this is right URL path url:'export.php', and check in browser console is your Ajax call is successfully hitting the server

Comment: Inspect browser, check  network->xhr. It has to show your Ajax function call

Comment: Yes, sir, I check it, and all is good, but why it doesn't start the exportation of excel file